# how to plot a line in python with an interval at each data point

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

Using python: I have a sequence of data points with means and a list with the standard deviation for each mean. I would like to plot the means as points connected by a solid line and the standard deviation as an halo around the line using the same color, but changed opacity and the width of the halo as an indication of the size of std. There is one plot which looks exactly like this: the [time series plot in Seaborn](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.tsplot.html#seaborn.tsplot) and the [Continuous Error Bars in Plotly](https://plot.ly/python/continuous-error-bars/): but the data model in the first is not suitable for my data as far as I can see and the output solution of the second is suboptimal for me. I haven't found a simple solution in Matplotlib. Obviously I could solve this by plotting the data points as lines from point to point and the std as a series of tetragons with different opacity. But maybe there is a more comfortable solution out there. 
Thanks in advance!

ps: 
my data looks like this:

means = [3, 5, 1, 8, 4, 6]

stds = [1.3, 2.6, 0.78, 3.01, 2.32, 2.9]

Comment: This should help: http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/errorbar_demo.html

Comment: thanks for the link. Not the kind of visualization I was looking for, but also a possible solution

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just do :

```
plt.plot (means)
plt.fill_between(range(6),means-stds,means+stds,alpha=.1)
```

For

[image]

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, thanks! ps: means - stds works for me only when I use a pandas series or numpy arrays, not with lists

Answer (score 2):

You can plot three lines (one for the mean and two - possibly transparent ones - for the deviations), and use [`matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between) to fill the areas between them.

Comment: thanks! same solution as the other one, but the other also provides a code snippet which is more helpful